# AutoMapper: Mapping child member from complex type to string[]

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-2

I have a destination type with a string[] property.

```
Animal
  string[] Barks;
```

My source object is:

```
  AnimalDTO
     List<BarkTypes> Barks;
```

How do I map **BarkTypes.NameOfBark** to the **string[] Barks**?

Something like this:?

```
Mapper.CreateMap<AnimalDTO, Animal>()
   .ForMember(dest => dest.Barks, y => y.MapFrom(x=>x.??????))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `ResolveUsing`:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<AnimalDTO, Animal>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Barks,
                    y => y.ResolveUsing(x=>x.Barks
                                            .Select(b=>b.NameOfBark)
                                            .ToArray())
              )
```

Comment: Is this method safer than using Martin's answer with a simple Select?

Comment: I don't think using `MapFrom` will work since that method requires an expression that points to a property.  Other than that they should be the same.

Answer (score 3):

Completely untested, but:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<AnimalDTO, Animal>()
   .ForMember(dest => dest.Barks, 
              y => y.MapFrom(x=>x.Barks
                                 .Select(z => z.NameOfBark)
                                 .ToArray());
```